# Is there any difference between Immersion and embedding?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Definition as below , I think they are same ,is right ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: An immersion does not need to be injective, at the very least. For example, $t \to e^{it}$ is an immersion of $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb C$.

Comment: How is this question missing details?

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD The question is poor-quality IMO, consisting of pasted images and no context from the OP, not even a proper statement of the problem. "Missing context or other details" isn't *exactly* the right reason, but it's used as a catch-all here and in many other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, immersions needn't be injective. Even if they are injective, they needn't be embeddings: consider the injective immersion of $(0,2\pi)$ in the plane as a figure eight, so that the point $(0,0)$ is the center of the cross. Explicitly, send $t\mapsto (2 \sin t,\sin(2t))$. This is an immersion that cannot be a homeomorphism onto its image, since the image has noncut points while $(0,2\pi)$ has none.

It is true, however, that every immersion is locally an embedding. This is deduced from the so called "constant rank theorems", for example.

Comment: Unrelated, but it is worth noting that if you add "properness" (which the figure 8 example violates) to your list of conditions, injective immersions do become embeddings. Namely, proper injective immersions are embeddings. (+1 by the way)